# TYPO3 logout if not accept

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I am currently developing an extension to display information for user after frontend login. The user has to accept them (like terms and conditions).

Now I am looking for a good and secure logout mechanism:

1. User gets redirect after login to information page

   - State: FE Login is available
2. User reads information, can click "Accept" and "Logout"

   - if Accept: redirect to user start page
   - if Logout: go to Loginpage with "logintype=logout"

Now here is the problem:

In step 2, user can enter any valid URL in Browser, and TYPO3 has valid FE Login already (Step 1) -> Page is displayed without accept.

First solution idea: Logout always at step 1, login again if click on Accept. But I don't know the user credentials for automatic login, is this possible somehow?

Second solution idea: add a cookie, and in TypoScript Template make a condition with redirect to logout. Not my favourite solution, as cookies are too easy to manipulate. And we always have strange problems with cookies, as some users are sharing their workstations.

Third solution idea: add a flag to fe_user table, if set redirect to logout. Problem: We have already performance issues. Is there a solution that dont increase the page loading time? I suppose this check has to be done with every page loading...

Do you have any solution ideas for that?

- TYPO3 4.5
- Extension is ExtBase
- add code to fe_login extension is a possible option, we have already changes there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't we use session? Set a session variable when the user clicks on accept and then use a typoscript condition like:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|accept > 0]
page.10.userFunc = tx_templavoila_pi1->main_page

[ELSE]
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = You are not allowed to visit this page
or
page.config >
page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://www.yourdomain.org/login.html
[END]
```

Comment: In fact, that is the cookie Solution, isn't it? So I can set the accept value to 1 in any firefox extension...

Comment: please check "Storing user-data or session-data" in this link:

http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.1.0/view/14/1/

Comment: If we can check the logged user details using "$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user ", then I think it's ok to set another session varible also for our requirements as mentioned above.

Comment: Hey thank you, I didn't know the difference between user-data and session data. I added my value as user-data and checked it with cookie editor, and you can't see any data, only a fe_user id like 5d2b4bf90f43ad1f1e9d41d4cf83aea3.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution code, if someone needs it:

1) Add user Key in the extension - there is no direct Cookie Access to that:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('user', 'acceptFromExtension', 1);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();
```

2) Remove Key if accepted:

```
if accepted {
  $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('user', 'acceptFromExtension', 0);
  $GLOBALS['TSFE']->storeSessionData();
}
```

2) Check Key with TypoScript - its stored in fe_user|uc:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|uc|acceptFromExtension> 0]
  page.config >
  page.config.additionalHeaders = Location: http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?id=111&logintype=logout
[END]
```

Thanks to sankar-v for that!

Answer (score 1):

While you have own extension, you can just programmically `logoff` the user in it and then redirect the browser to any other page (`$somePreparedUri` can be created in your extension or i.e. fetched from TypoScript - as a static value - depends on your needs)

```
if (!$accepted)
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->logoff(); 
    return $this->redirectToUri($somePreparedUri);   
)
```

Comment: But how can I login again if user clicks on accept? The problem is here the sequence, your code is never executed if user enters URL in browser

Comment: You are logging-in your user with other plugin (probably `fe_login`) before the redirect to the accept page, don't you? Actually you should write accept state in DB for each user, and check on every page that flag, otherwise, he'll just skip the acceptation, and will be able to go to the other page.

Comment: The best option for busy server would be just intercept login process (while you are modifying fe_login anyway) and add semi step for users who didn't accepted terms (flag stored in DB) before real logging.

Comment: I implemented the other solution now (see below), as far as I know a condition is not that bad with performance, as it can be cached. Just as because I am curious: do you know where login code is hidden in TYPO3 - fe_login is just the interface, not the real login code.